# How to improve query performance when using sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, reporting-services

First part of the query grabs `Policy`'s `Premiums`, `Effective` and `Expiration` dates. 
Second part creates `Calendar`, and third part (final `SELECT` statement) returns Earnings broken down by `Month` and `Year`
Everything works fine, takes just 3 seconds to display the result. 
But then I need to filter what `PolicyNumber`s to work with, basically I need to get rid of `PolicyNumber`'s that dont have `@ClassCode`. So for that in the first part of the query I placed `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE  State IN ('CA','NV','AZ')        
        AND PolicyNumber IN (
                            SELECT  PolicyNumber
                            FROM    tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial 
                            GROUP BY PolicyNumber
                            HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN ClassCode NOT IN (@ClassCode)                                                                       
 THEN 1 END)=0
                            )
```

Thanksful to @Prdp user I have this statement:  Case statement will generate 1 for the ClassCode that is present in the list else NULL will be generated. Now the count aggregate will count of 1 for each PolicyNumber. By setting = 0 we can make sure the PolicyNumber does not have any ClassCode present in given list.

After that query spinning forever, becase `@ClassCode` can have more that 200 `ClassCodes` in SSRS report.

Interesting things is that both those statements works fine separately. But when I use them together (which is placed that `WHERE` clause in `cte policy_data` then execution takes forever. 
Is any way to tell engine to do the first part of the query, which is

```
; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
   SELECT Cast(EOMONTH (GETDATE(), -1) AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
), policy_data AS (
    SELECT
        PolicyNumber
,       Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate
,       Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate
,       WrittenPremium
,       State
        FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
        WHERE  State IN ('CA','NV','AZ') 
    /* -------This statement gives me trouble ----------------------*/
        AND PolicyNumber IN (
                            SELECT  PolicyNumber
                            FROM    tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial 
                            GROUP BY PolicyNumber
                            HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN ClassCode NOT IN (5151)                                                                     
 THEN 1 END)=0
                            )
)
```

And then calculate and break down Earnings for only those policies that have been filtered.

My entire code is below:

```
; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
   SELECT Cast(EOMONTH (GETDATE(), -1) AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
), policy_data AS (
    SELECT
        PolicyNumber
,       Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate
,       Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate
,       WrittenPremium
,       State
        FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
        WHERE  State IN ('CA','NV','AZ') 
    /* -------This statement gives me trouble ----------------------*/
        AND PolicyNumber IN (
                            SELECT  PolicyNumber
                            FROM    tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial 
                            GROUP BY PolicyNumber
                            HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN ClassCode NOT IN (@ClassCode)                                                                       
 THEN 1 END)=0
                            )
)
, digits AS (
SELECT digit
   FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)
,      (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS z2 (digit)
), numbers AS (
SELECT 1000 * d4.digit + 100 * d3.digit + 10 * d2.digit + d1.digit AS number
    FROM digits AS d1
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d2
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d3
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d4
), calendar AS (
SELECT
    DateAdd(month, number, '1753-01-01') AS month_of
,   DateAdd(month, number, '1753-02-01') AS month_after
    FROM numbers
), policy_dates AS (
SELECT
   PolicyNumber
,   CASE
        WHEN month_of < PolicyEffectiveDate THEN PolicyEffectiveDate
        ELSE month_of
    END AS StartRiskMonth
,   CASE
       WHEN PolicyExpirationDate < month_after THEN PolicyExpirationDate
       WHEN Earned_to_date.Earned_to_date < month_after THEN Earned_to_date
       ELSE month_after
    END AS EndRiskMonth
,   DateDiff(day, PolicyEffectiveDate, PolicyExpirationDate) AS policy_days
,   WrittenPremium
    FROM policy_data
    JOIN calendar
        ON (policy_data.PolicyEffectiveDate < calendar.month_after
        AND calendar.month_of < policy_data.PolicyExpirationDate)
    CROSS JOIN Earned_to_date
    WHERE  month_of < Earned_to_date
)
SELECT      
            Year(StartRiskMonth) as YearStartRisk, 
            Month(StartRiskMonth) as MonthStartRisk,
            c.YearNum,c.MonthNum,
            convert(varchar(7), StartRiskMonth, 120) as RiskMonth,
            sum(WrittenPremium * DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) / policy_days) as EarnedPremium
FROM        tblCalendar  c
            LEFT  JOIN policy_dates l ON c.YearNum=Year(l.StartRiskMonth) AND c.MonthNum = Month(l.StartRiskMonth) 
            AND l.StartRiskMonth BETWEEN '01-01-2015' AND  '12-31-2016'
WHERE       c.YearNum Not IN (2017) 
GROUP BY    convert(varchar(7), StartRiskMonth, 120),
            Year(StartRiskMonth) , Month(StartRiskMonth),
            c.YearNum,c.MonthNum
ORDER BY    c.YearNum,c.MonthNum
```

What would be the best way to improve the performance?
I created `non-clustered` index on `PolicyNumber` on both tables. But still nothing.
Like I said, seems to me that if SQL Engine would process the first part(PolicyNumber filtering) that takes 3 seconds, and then do the second part (calculation for those PolicyNumber's) that takes another 3 seconds - that would be awesome. 
But I am new to DBA, so I am not sure that its even possible. 
Any advice?
Thanks

Execution Plan::

[image]
Final Result:

[image]

Comment: Codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for this

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your code more readable. Split it into smaller blocks via temp tables instead of cte.

Your trouble:

```
HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN ClassCode NOT IN (5151) THEN 1 END)=0
```

If ClassCode is 5000 in your having HAVING COUNT (TRUE -> 1).

If ClassCode is 5151 in your having HAVING COUNT (FALSE -> NULL).

should be filtered before group by:

```
WHERE ClassCode IN (5151) -- and check index
```

Comment: Table `tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial` doesnt have `NULL ClassCode`.
So will performance gonna get better if I break down it by Temp tables?
Thanks

Comment: When you split your code it'll be more readable and you rapidly change execution plan - you will much easier get information where are your performance issues or where your qry isn't returning correct data.